# Play geolocation module dependency for Play Framework 2.2

Tags: java, api, scala, playframework, dependencies

I am using Play Framework 2.2 (Scala). I want to add geo location web service to my project. I found the https://github.com/blabluble/play-geolocation-module module from http://www.playmodules.net/module/play-geolocation-module. When i am adding dependency

```
"com.edulify" % "geolocation_2.10" % "1.1.0
```

to my build.sbt file then the following error occured

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.edulify#geolocation_2.10;1.1.0: not found
```

I also tried the resolver given in the above link but it didn't work for me.
Can anybody tell me the dependencies for "Play geolocation module". 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `"geolocation_2.20"` instead?

Comment: @Jatin      "geolocation_2.20" didn't work. Is there any other alternatives for this dependency ?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything _at all_ in the documented repository: http://blabluble.github.com/modules/releases/ - it 404's

Comment: @millhouse yes it 404. But is there any other method to get rid of this problem  or should I use another module instead of "Play Geolocation Module"(Please suggest me one) ?